# Recursive relationship database

Tags: sql-server, recursive

So I have an university project that has to implement some kind of a recursive relationship like (for example - employee may be managed by other employee(https://www.sqa.org.uk/e-learning/SoftDevRDS02CD/page_49.htm)). Anyway I found it hard to think of an appropriate domain problem. Can you give me some examples? (Examples: categories of an online shop etc...)

Answer (score 1):

As well as management hierarchy, large businesses sometimes have divisional structures (country, area, region, city, branch) of fixed or variable depth. Geographic classification of places more generally could be a useful example too. Any taxonomy (books, living creatures, ...) or most other [classification systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Classification_systems), depending on any additional constraints you have been given.

Or family trees. If you ignore complications where parentage is not known or legally changes, both the maternal and paternal lines are potentially infinite tree structures. If you consider them both together rather than as two separate structures connecting the same set of nodes, they form a directed graph which might also be within your spec.

If graphs generally are allowed then that opens up the field even more: for instance places connected by roads, more general relationships between people, or links between articles on something like Wikipedia or the web more generally. Heading back to the more specific (and back to a tree/forest structure) the posts on forums like Reddit of HackerNews.

Recursive structures can appear everywhere that you model things connected or related to each other.

If you are looking for existing data sets to analyse rather than things to model, then there are a great many out there to be found. [/r/datasets](https://www.reddit.com/r/datasets/) might be a good place to start, for instance [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/datasets/comments/6v685o/complete_hacker_news_ycombinator_data_dump/) links to a dump of [HN](https://news.ycombinator.com/) data.

Comment: hm I thought about the forum ... What if the table Question&Answers has like CategoryId(foreign key to another table with the categories because the question must have a category then the answer must have a categoryId also)? Should I somehow split the questions and answers in separate tables?

Comment: There are several ways to arrange a forum data structure. StackExchange sites have a strict site->question->answer->comment structure functionally so the database is not unlikely to be laid out that way: separate entities for each type of thing rather than any recursive relationship. Sites like HN where comments can be responses to comments will have a recursive relationship between comment rows, and the initial post may also be a comment entry (a special case linked to a root node or with a NULL parent). Similarly tags here are single level but elsewhere tags/categories may be recursive.

Answer (score 0):

If you can think of a hierarchy (as @David Spillet has mentioned), then you could model a recursive relationship (instead of modelling the hierarchy as such, which would give you a set amount of levels eg DIRECTOR -< MANAGER -< EMPLOYEE ).  Another example: (part of an) ERD below - each ELEMENT may be the parent of one or more (child) ELEMENTS.

[image]

A (crude) implementation of your "forum" idea could look like this (Oracle 12c):

```
-- test table and data
create table hierarchy (
  id_ number primary key
, parent_ number references hierarchy( id_ )
, name_ varchar2(32)
);

-- the forum contains several questions
-- each question can have several answers
-- each answer can have several comments 
begin
 insert into hierarchy (id_, parent_, name_) 
   values ( 1 , null , 'forum' );
 insert into hierarchy (id_, parent_, name_) 
   values ( 2 , 1 , 'question1' );
 insert into hierarchy (id_, parent_, name_) 
   values ( 3 , 1 , 'question2' );
 insert into hierarchy (id_, parent_, name_) 
   values ( 4 , 2 , 'answer1' );
 insert into hierarchy (id_, parent_, name_) 
   values ( 5 , 2 , 'answer2' );
 insert into hierarchy (id_, parent_, name_) 
   values ( 6 , 3 , 'answer1' );
 insert into hierarchy (id_, parent_, name_) 
   values ( 7 , 2 , 'answer3' );
 insert into hierarchy (id_, parent_, name_) 
   values ( 8 , 5 , 'comment1' );
 insert into hierarchy (id_, parent_, name_) 
   values ( 9 , 5 , 'comment2' );
 insert into hierarchy (id_, parent_, name_) 
   values ( 10 , 6 , 'comment1' );
 insert into hierarchy (id_, parent_, name_) 
   values ( 11 , 6 , 'comment2' );
 insert into hierarchy (id_, parent_, name_) 
   values ( 12 , 6 , 'comment3' );
end;
/
```

The following query makes the "hierarchy" visible via the "paths".  It's more the result set of the query that is of importance here (not the query itself, as your question is labelled "sql-server").

```
select 
  id_
, case 
   when parent_ is null then '-' 
   else to_char( parent_ ) 
  end parent
, sys_connect_by_path( name_, '/' ) full_path
, name_
, level
from hierarchy
start with parent_ is null
connect by parent_ = prior id_ 
order by level, parent_, name_ ;

-- output

ID_ PARENT_ FULL_PATH                         NAME_          LEVEL
1   null    /forum                            forum          1
2   1       /forum/question1                  question1      2
3   1       /forum/question2                  question2      2
4   2       /forum/question1/answer1          answer1        3
5   2       /forum/question1/answer2          answer2        3
7   2       /forum/question1/answer3          answer3        3
6   3       /forum/question2/answer1          answer1        3
8   5       /forum/question1/answer2/comment1 comment1       4
9   5       /forum/question1/answer2/comment2 comment2       4
10  6       /forum/question2/answer1/comment1 comment1       4
11  6       /forum/question2/answer1/comment2 comment2       4
12  6       /forum/question2/answer1/comment3 comment3       4
```

Dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=be13709a2dcac99d15519c79b1018a27).  See also: [Hierarchical queries](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/queries003.htm#SQLRF52332) (Oracle documentation).

Comment: For recursive queries in SQL Server (or prostgres/sqlite/mariadb) use a recursive Common Table Expression (CTE): https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html, https://sqlite.org/lang_with.html, https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/with/)

Comment: @DavidSpillett: Cheers David, much appreciated! I shall have a look at this.